# Buble sort code for homework doesn't work as expected

Tags: c, sorting, multidimensional-array, c-strings, strcmp

I have task to make a program that can sort names.

The output of the program:

```
How many names will be inputed? 3
Angelia Kho
Angel
Angelina

Sorted Names(Ascending):
1. Angel
2. Angelia Kho
3. Angelina
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    char ignore;
    
    printf("How Many names will be inputed? ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    
    scanf("%c", &ignore);
    
    char names [a][255];
    char temp [255];
    
    int j;
    for(j = 0; j < a; j++){
        scanf("%[^\n]", names[j]);
        scanf("%c", &ignore);
    }
    
    int i;
    
    for(i = 0; i<a; i++)
    {
        for(j = i; j<a; j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(names[i], names[j]> 0))
            {
                strcpy(temp, names[i]);
                strcpy(names[i], names[j]);
                strcpy(names[j],temp);
            }
        }
    }
    
    printf("\nsorted names(Ascending): \n");
    for(i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        printf("%d. %[^\n]", i, names[i]);
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
[Warning]passing argument 2 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without cast
```

But, it still working until user input

Output for now:

```
How Many names will be inputed? 3
Angelia Kho
Angel
Angelina

--------------------------------
Process exited after 23.08 seconds with return value 3221225477
Press any key to continue...
```

Comment: Is this C++ code or C code? They're two separate languages, and suggestions that are appropriate for C++ will be invalid for C. From the looks of your current code, this is actually a C question.

Comment: `passing argument 2 of 'strcmp' makes pointer from integer without cast`: this warning is almost always an error. Don't expect your code to work as long as this warning shows up

Comment: yes this is the c code im sorry for the tag

Comment: Following up on @Jabberwocky 's observation: `if(strcmp(names[i], names[j]> 0))` should almost certainly be `if(strcmp(names[i], names[j]) > 0)`. (You want to compare the result of the `strcmp` to `0`, not `names[j]`.)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I already changed my code and now it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For starters calls like this

```
scanf("%c", &ignore);
```

are redundant. You may remove them and change the call of scanf for entering strings the following way

```
scanf( " %254[^\n]", names[j] );
       ^^^
```

Pay attention to the leading space in the format string. It allows to skip white space characters as for example the new line character `'\n'` stored in the input buffer after a preceding call of `scanf`.

In the if statement

```
if(strcmp(names[i], names[j]> 0))
```

there is a typo. The expression `names[j] > 0`  has the type `int` and is equal to 1.

You have to write

```
if(strcmp(names[i], names[j] ) > 0 )
```

Another typo in this call of `printf`

```
printf("%d. %[^\n]", i, names[i]);
```

Rewrote it like

```
printf("%d. %s\n", i, names[i]);
```

Also the used method of sorting is not the bubble sort method. It looks like the selection sort method with redundant swaps.